# Mysql Join and get 2 values?

Tags: mysql

I have table with values like this

```
TABLE1
ID....VALUE
-----------
1.....Hello
2.....World
3.....Other
4.....Words
```

And another table with keys

```
TABLE2
ID...WORD1...WORD2...OTHER...FIELDS
-----------------------------------
1.....1.......1......NULL....NULL..
2.....1.......3......NULL....NULL..
3.....4.......1......NULL....NULL..
```

What i want to do is joining these two so that it produces something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM `TABLE2` ...
=
Hello Hello
Hello Other
Words Hello
```

But i'm totally lost!

Comment: What do these table have in common ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
select t1a.word, t1b.word from 
TABLE2 t2
join table1 t1a on t2.word1 = t1a.ID
join table1 t1b on t2.word2 = t1b.ID
```

You can join a table as many times as you'd like to the original table, as long as you make sure to have unique aliases for each instance of the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1a.value, t1b.value
FROM table2 
JOIN table1 as t1a on word1 = t1a.id
JOIN table1 as t1b on word2 = t1b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select t1.VALUE, t3.VALUE as value2 from 
   Table2 t2
   join Table1 t1 on t2.WORD1 = t1.ID
   join table1 t3 on t2.WORD2 = t3.ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83fe8/9)